# PHP Writing Complex Order Info to CSV

Tags: php, csv, fwrite

I am writing an order exporter in PHP and am having difficulty with php checking a csv header and then writing to a file.

I have my code which opens the file, then writes to the csv

```
$fh = fopen($file_compile, 'w');
```

I then write my header:

```
$header = '"OrderId", "Customer";

foreach ($products as $product) {
  $header .= ', "' . $product . '"';
}

fputs($fh, $header . "\n");
```

which gives me an output

[image]

I now generate my `$line` array

which outputs:

```
array(3) {
  ["OrderId"]=>
  string(9) "100000033"
  ["Customer"]=>
  string(14) "Graeme Houston"
  ["total"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["Socks"]=>
    int(12)
    ["Books"]=>
    int(23)
    ["Wallets"]=>
    int(12)
  }
}
```

Now as you can see, my array doesn't exactly match the CSV above it, which is fine, what I would like to achieve is, if there is a value in the `total` that matches a value in the header, to but the integer value in the cell. (scratches head)

To illustrate:

[image]

I must add I have been trying to figure this out for a few days, I cant get my head round it, hence the post on here. I would be extremely grateful if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: cant really explain my idea, but if you post a header array and line array in php, i will mock up an idea i have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that complex...

```
$header = array('OrderId','Customer');

foreach ($products as $product) {
  $header[] = $product;
}

$tmp = '"' .implode('","',$header) . '"';

fputs($fh, $tmp . "\n");
```

For your header construction... Then for you line output something similar to:

```
foreach($header as $key){
    if(empty($line[$key])) $line[$key] = NULL;

    if(empty($line[$key]) && !empty($line['total'][$key])){
         $line[$key] = $line['total'][$key];
    }
}
unset($line['total']);
```

Now you've filled the gaps for non-existent columns, and given values to the existent ones.

Comment: Thank you, works a treat, I may actually sleep tonight! ha ha